# Current measurement USB to serial UART converter or Arduino

Tags: current-measurement

I want to perform a current measurement of an electronic module with the help of a multimeter with log function.

Can I just couple the module to a USB to TTL serial UART converter and perform the current measurement or do I need to connect it to an Arduino where it will be used later to get more accurate results?

Comment: How will that be able to measure current?

Comment: 1) The Arduino isn't going to add any accuracy, that's entirely down to the multimeter. 2) The USB to UART interface only allows you to connect two things together, it doesn't add any actual functionality itself. What you need to use depends on what interface your meter has and what you're connecting it to.

Comment: Ok lets phrase it different, will i get the same current measurements results for both options, or will they be different due to the load of the arduino/USB to serial UART converter?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a multimeter to read any different because it's hooked up to a data logger unless you introduce ground loops or noise as a result. So it's down to your meter manufacturer and specification.

Comment: Your multimeter will measure the current draw of any devices connected 'downstream' from it. So if you connect more 'stuff' downstream then yes the measurements will be different.